# Magento 2 : after upgrading magento 2 with command site not working

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade

After upgrading the Magento 2, the following error is showing in browser:

> exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Can't create directory /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/.'
>   in
>   /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115
>   Stack trace: 0
>   /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Framewo...')
>   1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Framewo...')
>   2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Framewo...') 3 /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') 4
>   /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...')
>   5 /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Framewo...')
>   6 /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...')
>   7 /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...')
>   8 /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array,
>   'Magento\Framewo...', NULL, 'response', 'Magento\Framewo...') 9
>   /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Framewo...',
>   Array, Array) 10
>   /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...',
>   Array) 11
>   /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(233):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewo...',
>   Array) 12 /home/saudifishcorner/public_html/index.php(38):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framewo...')
>   13 {main}

Comment: Did you set  the permission?

Answer (score 3):

Remove **var/generation , var/cache ,var/page_cache** folder from your **magento2 root directory** and then **run below commands in sequence**.

- **sudo chmod -R 777 var**
- **php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer** (set the mode of
  environment is developer)
- **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**(it will generate all the proxies and
  dependencies )
- **php bin/magento setup:static-content:delpoy**(it will deploy all the
  static content)
- **php bin/magento cache:clean and php bin/magento cache:flush**(clear the
  cache)

**Note :** Make sure your **var and pub/static** folder have **writable permissions**

Answer (score 0):

run command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
```

and

```
sudo chmod -R 777 pub/
```

under magento2 root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign permission to var folder, 777
like we are changing in local with **chmod -R 777 var**

then this will work perfect, hope this will help,